# State is not updating in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm building a webapp using React and Google maps. I want to calculate distance between 2 places using driving. I'm getting an error when updating state, i'm not sure what's wrong.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

I've indicated the error line in the code.
I know that `setState` is asynchronous and `useEffect` normally helps with this.
I tried placing that `setState` in its own `useEffect` but that still gave an error.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  useJsApiLoader,
  Autocomplete,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

const center = { lat: 48.8584, lng: 2.2945 };

export default function Test() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */ (null));
  const [directionsResponse, setDirectionsResponse] = useState(null);
  const [distanceText, setDistanceText] = useState();
  const [durationText, setDurationText] = useState();
  const [distanceCalc, setDistanceCalc] = useState();
  const [durationCalc, setDurationCalc] = useState();
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "google-map-script",
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLEMAPS_KEY,
    libraries: ["maps", "places"],
  });

  /** @type React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement> */
  const originRef = useRef();
  /** @type React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement> */
  const destinationRef = useRef();

  const calculateRoute = async () => {
    console.log("Clicked");

    if (originRef.current.value === "" || destinationRef.current.value === "") {
      return;
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const mapResult = await directionsService.route({
      origin: originRef.current.value,
      destination: destinationRef.current.value,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    });

    setResult(mapResult);

    console.log("Result2: ", result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I'm being triggered");
    if (result) {
      setDistanceText(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text); //error line
      setDurationText(result.routes[0].leg[0].duration.text);  //error line
      setDistanceCalc(result.routes[0].leg[0].distance.value); //error line
      setDurationCalc(result.routes[0].leg[0].duration.value); //error line
    }
  }, [result]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Distance Text: ", distanceText);
    console.log("Duration Text: ", durationText);
    console.log("Distance Calc: ", distanceCalc);
    console.log("Distance Calc: ", durationCalc);
  }, [distanceText, durationText, durationCalc, distanceCalc]);

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Origin" ref={originRef} />
      </Autocomplete>
      <Autocomplete>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Destination" ref={destinationRef} />
      </Autocomplete>
      <button onClick={() => calculateRoute()}>Calculate</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing either `result` is undefined or something in `result` is undefined. What is the output of `console.log(result)` if put in the `if (result) {` block?

Comment: @mandy8055 how would you set state to something coming from an API then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I'm being triggered");

    if (result) {
      setDistanceText(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text); //error line
      setDurationText(result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);  //error line
      setDistanceCalc(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value); //error line
      setDurationCalc(result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value); //error line
    }
  }, [result]);
```

There are typos in your code where you are using **leg** instead of **legs**. Update your useEffect code with above code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code :

```
  useEffect(() => {
          console.log("I'm being triggered");
          if (result) {
            const route = result.routes[0];
            if (route && route.legs && route.legs[0]) {
              const leg = route.legs[0];
              if (leg.distance && leg.duration) {
                setDistanceText(leg.distance.text);
                setDurationText(leg.duration.text);
                setDistanceCalc(leg.distance.value);
                setDurationCalc(leg.duration.value);
              }
            }
          }
        }, [result]);
```